# Unable to install ROS2 on ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS because of an error due to ROS packages

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, installation

I have ran into an error whilst trying to install ROS2, not sure what to do.

Some background:

I'm running ubuntu version 22.04.3 using a virtual machine.
I'm trying to install ROS 2 Iron (installation process is described here:

https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

This is the command I'm entering in the terminal and the message its returning:

```
 tempo@Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
    sudo add-apt-repository universe
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      python3-software-properties software-properties-gtk
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      python3-software-properties software-properties-common
      software-properties-gtk
    3 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 64 not to upgrade.
    Need to get 114 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
    Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.99.22.8 [14.1 kB]
    Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 software-properties-gtk all 0.99.22.8 [71.3 kB]
    Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.99.22.8 [28.8 kB]
    Fetched 114 kB in 0s (1,650 kB/s)                      
    (Reading database ... 245669 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-common_0.99.22.8_all.deb ...
    Unpacking software-properties-common (0.99.22.8) over (0.99.22.7) ...
    Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-gtk_0.99.22.8_all.deb ...
    Unpacking software-properties-gtk (0.99.22.8) over (0.99.22.7) ...
    Preparing to unpack .../python3-software-properties_0.99.22.8_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python3-software-properties (0.99.22.8) over (0.99.22.7) ...
    Setting up python3-software-properties (0.99.22.8) ...
    Setting up software-properties-common (0.99.22.8) ...
    Setting up software-properties-gtk (0.99.22.8) ...
    Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...
    Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
    Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
    Adding component(s) 'universe' to all repositories.
    Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
    Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
    Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]     
    Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
    Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]      
    Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease                       
    Hit:6 http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable jammy InRelease   
    Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release                         
      404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
    Get:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease [4,682 B]
    Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    W: http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
    W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
    W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
```

I've tried doing a sudo apt update but that didn't solve the issue. Someone was having a similar issue here: The repository does not have a Release file but I couldn't find the line and file that was referred to in the solution.

Please let me know if you need more information